# Angular 4 - Executar função somente quando variavel for alterada

Tags: javascript, angular

Preciso executar uma função, mais ela só pode rodar caso a variável esteja como false.

Qual contexto: Ao pressionar TAB o sistema chama a função (fnTab). Essa função realiza uma pesquisa no banco e imprime a descrição no input. Porém, caso o usuário seja muito rapido no click dos tab, ele irá imprimir a descrição do input do proximo registro e não no atual.

Comment: O que você tem de código para nos mostrar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode chamar esse método utilizando o evento "change" do elemento input, assim, quando a variável (no caso o conteúdo do input) for alterado, o método é chamado.Ex.:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="suaVariavel" (change)="seuMetodo($event)" />
```

Lembrando que se você pretende alterar o valor dessa variável através do código, a linha acima irá gerar um loop infinito, pois tanto o ngModel quanto seu método estarão tentando alterar a mesma variável, se for este o caso, melhor utilizar a alternativa abaixo:

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="suaVariavel" (ngModelChange)="seuMetodo($event)" />
```

Observe que ao utilizar o (change), a chamada do método só irá ocorrer quando o campo perder o foco, mas o método será chamado com as informações do campo correto.